# Проверка подписки на канал

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Как сделать проверку подписки на приватный канал?
Выдает ошибку что чат не найден.
пробывал так:

```py
chatid = 1234567890
userid = 987654321
await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=f"{chatid}", user_id=f"{userid}")
```

Также пробывал вводить айди с минусом

```py
chatid = -1234567890
```

Пробывал вводить айди как строку

```py
chatid = "1234567890"
```

Пробывал вводить ссылку на канал, пробывал вводить ссылку без `https://`, пробывал вводить ссылку без `t.me/`
Ничего не помогло, в интернете решения не нашел или я плохо ищу.

Работает только с публичными каналами вот так:

```py
chatid = "@channel"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К айди канала нужно добавить `-100`, тоесть было `123456789` стало `-100123456789`.